# Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' Error

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift3

I am having an issue with swift 3 when I am trying to connect a Slide out Menu to another *ViewController* but I am getting an issue with the prepareforsegue.

## Here is my code.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
 {        
    let DestVC = segue.destination as! ViewControllerSlide
```

**Here is where I am getting my error. ^^^**

```
    var indexPath : IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    
    DestVC.varView = indexPath.row 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Probably your segue is pointing to an `UINavigationController`, try assign the destination with that first:

```
let destVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
let slideVC = destVC.topViewController as! ViewControllerSlide
//...
```